# Create Order from Input Itm/Qty Looked up against Bill of Materials

Tags: excel, lookup

Not sure the best way to ask this so please feel free to ask for more information!

I have our Bill of Materials in a spreadsheet, column A is the "parent" item, column B has the "components"

I want to create a spreadsheet where i can type

```
Parent - Qty
Parent - Qty
Parent - Qty
etc
```

and then in turn make a list of components i need to order.

i have the lookup part done to find the components that go with each parent once the parent is entered, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to take all of the components, get them in a list, remove duplicates, and then look back at the quantity to see how many of each component I need to order.

Attaching a screenshot of where i am right now for reference...
**NOTES:**
+ never more than 5 components per item
+ each component only goes into the parent once (qty per is 1)
+ components can be on multiple parents

Help!

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: So did you already do an index/match lookup? Something like `=IFERROR(INDEX(ComponentList,SMALL(IF(ParentList=E2,ROW(ParentList)-ROW(INDEX(ParentList,1,1))+1),1)),"")` ? Can you show what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: I'm hoping to get
component - total qty
component - total qty
etc as the output format. with no duplicates and the quantities summarized.